# Regex match group but don't include in result

Tags: regex

I am trying to find a group of IDs from an web page html source code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js"> <!--<![endif]-->
<head>
<body>
 <script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
     jQuery(document).ready(function(){
     jQuery('#Grid').tGrid({
     pageSize:["5","10","20","50"],
     myIds: [1765,1706,1809,1847,1857], 
     add: 'url/add'}); });
    //]]>
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I wan't to extract all the values for `myIds` in this format `1765,1706,1809,1847,1857`

So far tried these:

```
(myIds:\s)\[(.*?)\]
```

**matches** `myIds: [1765,1706,1809,1847,1857]`

```
(?!myIds:\s)\[(.*?)\]
```

**matches** `[1765,1706,1809,1847,1857]`, `["5","10","20","50"]`, `[if gt IE 8]`, `[endif]`

How can i get values of `myIds`.

Comment: use this `(allAssetIds:\s)(?:\[(.*?)\])` and get the value from group index 2. But there isn't a sting `allAssetIds:` in your input.

Comment: I have posted one snippet of the HTML which itself is quite big, For the second regex query it returns around 13 matches. So haven't gone for index.

Comment: Why don't you try a html parser instead of using regex?

Comment: We have a extraction rule plugin in our web performance test which gets string by regex. If this doesn't work then I would probably write a custom plugin with HTMLAgilityPack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\s*myIds.*?\[(.*?)\]
```

This works.

See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/iX5xR2/20

Comment: ^\s*myIds.*?\[(.*?)\], try this.

Comment: Ignore my above comment. Solution is working in both the sites. I just had to look for Group 1. Thanks.